# Handle Vue render errors locally

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue (server side rendered) with mjml to generate emails.

So I have something (overly simplified) like:

```
<mjml><mj-body>Hello {{ User.Name }}</mj-body></mjml>
```

If the model doesn't define `User` then Vue throws an error and the whole output is lost.

What I want to the output to be along the lines:

```
<mjml><mj-body>Hello <error>'User' is undefined</error></mj-body></mjml>
```

I have implemented `Vue.config.errorHandler` but that just tells me about the error -- there is no rendered output.

Anyway to implement the equivalent of an error handler around each variable substitution?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vue version >= 2.5, you can use `errorCaptured` to create an `ErrorBoundary`

```
const ErrorBoundary = {
  name: 'ErrorBoundary',
  data: () => ({
    error: false,
    msg: ''
  }),
  errorCaptured (err, vm, info) {
    this.error = true
    this.msg = `${err.stack}\n\nfound in ${info} of component`
  },
  render (h) {
    return this.error 
      ? h('pre', this.msg) 
      : this.$slots.default[0]
  }
}
```

and use this in your component

```
  <error-boundary>
    <mjml><mj-body>Hello {{ User.Name }}</mj-body></mjml>
  </error-boundary>
```

If the application has any javascript error, it will be displayed on UI

[image]

Example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/Vgqzvj)

If you want to have more user-friendly error, you can customize ErrorBoundary to have fallback to another component. You can find out in [this tutorial](https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/blob/3ff509bd3c2d345262f18113ed79fcb9a395a457/src/v2/cookbook/handling-errors-with-error-boundaries.md)

Another [good example](https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/g7vt350n/) of using `errorHandler`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this works for my use case which is specially for template substitutions inside {{ ... }}

If I replace the <app-counter></app-counter> component with {{ ZZZ }} then there is no output and the ErrorBoundary component's errorCaptured event doesn't seem to get called.